# 403 on POST preflight (sometimes)

Tags: spring, http, nginx, cors

I have a Spring Boot server behind an Nginx reverse proxy, that I access using fetch from a React app. The frontend is served from another port, so I have to enable CORS on the server. In most cases this works great, but about 1% of my users get a 403 in response to the OPTIONS preflight request, and I need help figuring out why. The biggest problem I have is that I'm unable to replicate the issue on any of my machines.

Spring Boot CORS config:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("https://example.com");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Nginx config (3000 is NodeJS serving frontend and 3001 is Spring Boot):

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ...
}
```

Nginx log format (I removed some parts for clarity):

```
"$request" $status "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"
```

By looking at the Nginx access.log I've nailed down 2 types of log rows where 403's show:

```
"OPTIONS /api/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user%40example.com&password=****" 403 "https://www.example.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

meaning Windows 7 running Chrome 61, and

```
"OPTIONS /api/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user%40example.com&password=****" 403 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

meaning Windows 7 running IE11.

*Other users using the same setup of OS and browser experience no problems.*

Data manually sent with fetch:

```
URL: https://example.com:3001/api/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user%40example.com&password=****
Method: POST
Headers:
    Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXX=
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: undefined
```

Actual parameters in the preflight request for a working user (from Chrome console):

**Request headers:**

```
OPTIONS /api/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user%40example.com&password=**** HTTP/1.1
Host: https://example.com:3001
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: https://example.com:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.79 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: https://example.com:3000/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
```

**Response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 16:01:37 GMT
```

My guess would be that there is something wrong with the way I send the fetch request, or that I've configured the headers incorrectly. But so far I've not been able to solve it.

Any help would be mighty appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to find the error, and it was my own fault completely.

As can be seen in the Nginx access.log, one of the failed preflights has an `$http_referer`, that is the Origin Header, of `www.example.com/login`. This will of course fail a preflight since my CORS config only allows `example.com`, **without the `www` subdomain**.

I've fixed this by adding `server` blocks to the Nginx config so that all requests from the `www` subdomain return a redirect to the non-`www` domain, using a `301 Permanently moved`:

```
server {
    ...

    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api/v1/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ...
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Note that I also redirect all `http` traffic to `https` in order to keep everything encrypted.

This way I can be sure all requests are entering my 2 servers using `https://example.com` as origin, and there is no need to modify the CORS configuration.